# Scala IDE Search Dialog

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide

I'm using the Scala IDE (the latest version, I think: 3.0.2-vfinal-20131028-1923-Typesafe)

I've been doing some refactoring and cleared up some old code. Now, whenever I press Control-H (search menu), it comes up with an error saying `"An error occurred while creating the search page 'Java Search'. Reason: <file> does not exist"`

`<file>` is a one of the files I deleted when refactoring.

This problem affects all projects, even those which aren't dependant on the project which previously contained `<file>`.

I've tried the following:

- Regenerated the project files (they're generated by sbt) and refreshed them in Scala IDE
- Removed the projects from Scala IDE entirely, and re-imported them
- Cleaned all projects within Scala IDE

None of these have solved the problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a bug, could you file a ticket with the stack trace on the project's issue tracker (In the Scala menu, there's a "Report a Bug" entry)?

Comment: The "Report a Bug" entry takes me to the Assembla website, but then I can't create a ticket without creating an account and creating a project of my own. What's the way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Fast forward 2015, this still wasn't fixed

There's an answer already on SO, maybe you've found it : [Eclipse stuck for search dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593141/eclipse-stuck-for-search-dialog-box) . I've experienced the same problem (twice!) and the simple fix of creating dummy files and then deleting them worked.

This should have been a comment ofc but my reputation is far too low.